# Help to understand if an equation is possible to model impact

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I’m looking for an equation that express the relationship between Sales and the Star Rating %.     I want to model what a drop in sales will do to the Star Rating %

Star rating reviews received are typically currently distributed in the ratios below based on currently volumes.

| Star Rating | % of reviews at that rating |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 69 |
| 4 | 14 |
| 3 | 8 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 7 |

Reviews drop proportionally with sales .  The volume of reviews is measured.     What is interesting is when reviews drop it is overwhelming the 4 and 5 star reviews that are impacted.   1  -3 star rating volumes  tend to be very constant on products at the scale of review volumes.

e.g.   I have a case where reviews dropped in volume from 50 000 to 25 000 over a period and while the ratios changed to the list above, the actual volume of 1 – 3 star reviews was static .  Only 4 and 5 star reviews diminished.

Is it possible to create an equation to model the impact on star rating % based on an increase / decrease in sales ?

My maths capability is limited so please be kind :)

Comment: The problem for me is not with math, it is with the terms you use. When you say "The volume of reviews" : which "reviews" are you speaking about ? Please take a concrete example : for example you sell music disks which are rated such and such ; a "review" is, in this case is  ...

Comment: Do you have access to Excel or Google Sheets? If yes, then first thing is plot the data and find out what type of function fits the data well. But you do not have enough data to make a robust model.

Comment: Once again, what do you call a "review" ?

Comment: Hi Jean Marie , Let me clarify hopefully. 
We receive all types of products and customer can leave a review .  The review is rated 1 to 5 .    The total number of reviews received is a proportion of sales as not everyone likes to receive a review .  
We have a metric for the average rating per product category .  
What I’m trying to express is the impact that a drop in sales has on the review % as when the reviews drop due to drop on sales it is overwhelming the 4 and 5 star reviews which are “lost” .   Hopefully this is a little clearer .

Comment: I appreciate there will be some assumptions that are required but I’m hoping there can be a formula that can help me understand that if sales drop by 20%. I can expect a change in star rating %  to be X .